# Python error when installing Cryptography via pip

Tags: windows, installation, python, pip

I want to install the `cryptography` package, but when I run `pip install cryptography`, I'm getting a lot of errors. I have tried to find a solution on Google, but still haven't found it.

Here are the screenshots of the error.

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]
[image: screenshot3]
[image: screenshot4]

Comment: In the future, please post errors as text so it can be searchable for those having this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method,

Download python `.whl` files from any of the below links.

[Python 3.7 - Windows 32bit](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/c9/574f2cffcd4b9213b019b25ac158d71e17b549a43cb5f0912b418c2f06e2/cryptography-2.7-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl)

[Python 3.7 - Windows 64bit](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/73/fc8c85104bd316086a7717d4970aec5e05fafcd6b9bf7257fe3621b180a0/cryptography-2.7-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl)

Then run,

```
pip install cryptography-xyz.whl
```

Comment: I use windows, are you sure I must download cryptography-2.7-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl ? Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Codelt thank you, I use python 3.8 and use windows 64 bit